Which activation function for multi-class classification gives true probability (softmax vs sigmoid)
I'm wondering which activation function for multi class classification problem, give true probability.
According to:
https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/are-softmax-outputs-of-classifiers-true-probabilities
it seems that the output probability (for softmax) doesn't represent the true probability.
Is this the same when we use sigmoid function ?
Are sigmoid probabilities (for each class) more relivable than softmax ?

They don't represent true probability because you'd still have to calibrate your model.
Let's imagine you're trying to classify cats and dogs in a given set of images (binary classification problem, with 0 for cats and 1 for dogs). Now let's say you have a batch of 10 images as the input of your model. If, for all 10 samples, your model assigns a probability of 0.6 that they are the positive class, then you'd expect (for a well-calibrated model) to find 4 cat images and 6 dog images in your batch. After all, that's what a probability means.
Using a sigmoid won't fix your calibration problem, as your model won't even have a probability distribution as its output. You'd need to use an extra data split (if you can afford to use one) and use calibration curves to evaluate your model's calibration. Scikit-learn has a pretty insightful read on the matter.
Some other references as well, these are specific to neural networks:

GUO et al., 2017;
VASILEV, Ruslan; D'YAKONOV, Alexander; 2023.


I will refine my question:
If the last layer has the size of 2 neurons and I have extra data split which (for binary classification) the total accuracy is 95% (and for dog the accuracy is 93%  and 97% for cat).
Now I have a new sample and I'm using softmax. The values of the neurons after softmax are:  [0.01, 0.99] -  I will classify it as dog.
My quest is:
Can I say that the model is sure it's a dog in 99% ? (or that value means nothing and used just as a threshold for classification dog or cat) ?

Unless the model is well-calibrated, you can not interpret that 99% value as a confidence level. Let's say you have 990 images of dogs and 10 images of cats. If the model is well-calibrated and it were to assign an output of [0.01, 0.99] to every single image, then you would be able to interpret such values as a confidence level (i.e. out of N images, 0.99*N are dogs). Now if the model is poorly-calibrated and it were to assign [0.3, 0.7], then you would not be able to do the same, even though the model achieved the same accuracy as in the 1st scenario.
